# Throttle onQueryTextChange in SearchView

Tags: java, android, search, searchview, android-search

What's the best way to "throttle" `onQueryTextChange` so that my `performSearch()` method is called only once every second instead of every time the user types?

```
public boolean onQueryTextChange(final String newText) {
    if (newText.length() > 3) {
        // throttle to call performSearch once every second
        performSearch(nextText);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up with a solution similar to below. That way it should fire once every half second.

```
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(final String newText) {

            if (newText.length() > 3) {

                if (canRun) {
                    canRun = false;
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            canRun = true;
                            handleLocationSearch(newText);
                        }
                    }, 500);
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
```

Comment: this is a wrong solution. see pls https://proandroiddev.com/implementing-search-on-type-in-android-with-rxjava-9ece00f4e266

Comment: this solution lacks cancellation. you should keep in mind to remove callbacks from  handler if you no longer need to observe query text changes

Answer (score 29):

If you are using Kotlin and coroutines you could do the following:

```
var queryTextChangedJob: Job? = null

...

fun onQueryTextChange(query: String) {

    queryTextChangedJob?.cancel()
    
    queryTextChangedJob = launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
        delay(500)
        performSearch(query)
    }
}
```

Comment: Coroutines is the way forward! Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Thanks, @jc12, my code is mostly reduced.

Answer (score 25):

Building on aherrick's code, I have a better solution. Instead of using a boolean 'canRun', declare a runnable variable and clear the callback queue on the handler each time the query text is changed. This is the code I ended up using:

```
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(final String newText) {
    searchText = newText;

    // Remove all previous callbacks.
    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);

    runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Your code here.
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 500);

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I've come up to a solution using [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava), particularly it's [debounce](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/debounce.html) operator.

[image]

With Jake Wharton's handy [RxBinding](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding), we'll have this:

```
RxSearchView.queryTextChanges(searchView)
        .debounce(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // stream will go down after 1 second inactivity of user
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(new Consumer<CharSequence>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(@NonNull CharSequence charSequence) throws Exception {
                // perform necessary operation with `charSequence`
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 4):

1. Create abstract class:

   ```
   public abstract class DelayedOnQueryTextListener implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private Runnable runnable;

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        runnable = () -> onDelayerQueryTextChange(s);
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 400);
        return true;
    }

    public abstract void onDelayedQueryTextChange(String query);
   ```

   }
2. Set it like this:

   ```
   searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new DelayedOnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDelayedQueryTextChange(String query) {
            // Handle query
        }
    });
   ```

Answer (score 3):

**For Korlin**

In case of `coroutineScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {}` you may run into a problem `Suspend function '...' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function`.

I found the following way

```
private var queryTextChangedJob: Job? = null
private lateinit var searchText: String
```

Next don't forget use `implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.0-alpha05"`

```
override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {

    val text = newText ?: return false
    searchText = text

    queryTextChangedJob?.cancel()
    queryTextChangedJob = lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
        println("async work started...")
        delay(2000)
        doSearch()
        println("async work done!")
    }

    return false
}
```

If you want use `launch` inside ViewModel then use `implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.0-alpha05"`

```
queryTextChangedJob = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
        //...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily achieve it with [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava). Also, you will need [RxAndroid](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid) and [RxBinding](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding) (but you probably already have them in your project if you are using RxJava).

```
RxTextView.textChangeEvents(yourEditText)
          .debounce(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
          .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
          .subscribe(performSearch());
```

[Here](https://github.com/kaushikgopal/RxJava-Android-Samples/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/morihacky/android/rxjava/fragments/DebounceSearchEmitterFragment.java) the full example by Kaushik Gopal.

Comment: Thanks! However I'm not really interesting in bringing in RxJava at this point. Can it be done natively?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know any common clean solutions for this problem. I definitely could be achieved with Handler delays or Timer and TimerTasks.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find a solution that enable me to use some flow operators like `distinctUntilChanged` , utile I tried this approach, maybe someone need it:

First create an extension function from **SearchView**

```
private fun SearchView.getQueryTextChangeStateFlow(): StateFlow<String> {
    val query = MutableStateFlow("")
    
    setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
        override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
            return true
        }
        override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String): Boolean {
            query.value = newText
            return true
        }
    })

    return query
}
```

Then

```
 private fun setUpSearchStateFlow(searchView: SearchView) {
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        searchView.getQueryTextChangeStateFlow()
            .debounce(300)
            .distinctUntilChanged()
            .map { query ->
                startSearchRequestHere(query)
            }
            .flowOn(Dispatchers.Default)
            .collect {}
    }
}
```

[Reference](https://blog.mindorks.com/instant-search-using-kotlin-flow-operators)

Answer (score 0):

Using Coroutines and Flow:

```
private fun SearchView.onQueryTextChanged(): ReceiveChannel<String> =
    Channel<String>(capacity = Channel.UNLIMITED).also { channel ->
        setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
                return false
            }

            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
                newText.orEmpty().let(channel::offer)
                return true
            }
        })
    }

@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
fun <T> ReceiveChannel<T>.debounce(time: Long, unit: TimeUnit = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, scope: CoroutineScope): ReceiveChannel<T> =
    Channel<T>(capacity = Channel.CONFLATED).also { channel ->
        scope.launch {
            var value = receive()
            whileSelect {
                onTimeout(time) {
                    channel.offer(value)
                    value = receive()
                    true
                }
                onReceive {
                    value = it
                    true
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And add to your search view like this:

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
   searchView.onQueryTextChanged().debounce(time = 500, scope = lifecycleScope).consumeEach { newText ->
          //Use debounced query
   }
}
```