# Kotlin Android debounce

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions, kotlin-extension, kotlinx.coroutines

Is there any fancy way to implement `debounce` logic with Kotlin Android?

I'm not using Rx in project.

There is a way in [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742210/implementing-debounce-in-java), but it is too big as for me here.

Comment: Are you looking for a coroutine-based solution?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Yes, as I understood it would be very efficient.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Throttle onQueryTextChange in SearchView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34955109/throttle-onquerytextchange-in-searchview)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50007453/2413303 this guy had a co-routine answer on the question i marked duplicate.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Would try out and update, but the question seems different then that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use *kotlin coroutines* to achieve that.
[Here is an example](https://gist.github.com/k-kagurazaka/54441d6d5dfdb5668fd884008cd480a2).

Be aware that *coroutines* are [experimental at kotlin 1.1+](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines.html#experimental-status-of-coroutines) and it may be changed in upcoming kotlin versions.

#### UPDATE

Since [Kotlin 1.3](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew13.html) release, *coroutines* are now stable.

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to be out of date now that 1.3.x has been released.

Comment: @JoshuaKing, yes. Maybe https://medium.com/@pro100svitlo/edittext-debounce-with-kotlin-coroutines-fd134d54f4e9 will help. I will try later.

Comment: Thanks! Because this is super useful, but I need to update. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that Channels are considered stable?

Comment: A curiosity: why almost all the solutions propose the use of ***coroutines***, forcing among the rest to add a specific dependency (the question does not say that the coroutines are already in use)? For such a simple operation, don't they add unnecessary overhead? Isn't it better to use **`System.currentTimeMillis()`** or similar?

Answer (score 72):

For a simple approach from inside a `ViewModel`, you can just launch a job within the `viewModelScope`, keep track of the job, and cancel it if a new value arises before the job is complete:

```
private var searchJob: Job? = null

fun searchDebounced(searchText: String) {
    searchJob?.cancel()
    searchJob = viewModelScope.launch {
        delay(500)
        search(searchText)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 68):

I've created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/Terenfear/a84863be501d3399889455f391eeefe5) with three debounce operators inspired by [this elegant solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55802898/5102726) from [Patrick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/751581/patrick) where I added two more similar cases: `throttleFirst` and `throttleLatest`. Both of these are very similar to their RxJava analogues ([throttleFirst](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Filtering-Observables#throttlefirst), [throttleLatest](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Filtering-Observables#throttlelatest)).

`throttleLatest` works similar to `debounce` but it operates on time intervals and returns the latest data for each one, which allows you to get and process intermediate data if you need to.

```
fun <T> throttleLatest(
    intervalMs: Long = 300L,
    coroutineScope: CoroutineScope,
    destinationFunction: (T) -> Unit
): (T) -> Unit {
    var throttleJob: Job? = null
    var latestParam: T
    return { param: T ->
        latestParam = param
        if (throttleJob?.isCompleted != false) {
            throttleJob = coroutineScope.launch {
                delay(intervalMs)
                latestParam.let(destinationFunction)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`throttleFirst` is useful when you need to process the first call right away and then skip subsequent calls for some time to avoid undesired behavior (avoid starting two identical activities on Android, for example).

```
fun <T> throttleFirst(
    skipMs: Long = 300L,
    coroutineScope: CoroutineScope,
    destinationFunction: (T) -> Unit
): (T) -> Unit {
    var throttleJob: Job? = null
    return { param: T ->
        if (throttleJob?.isCompleted != false) {
            throttleJob = coroutineScope.launch {
                destinationFunction(param)
                delay(skipMs)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`debounce` helps to detect the state when no new data is submitted for some time, effectively allowing you to process a data when the input is completed.

```
fun <T> debounce(
    waitMs: Long = 300L,
    coroutineScope: CoroutineScope,
    destinationFunction: (T) -> Unit
): (T) -> Unit {
    var debounceJob: Job? = null
    return { param: T ->
        debounceJob?.cancel()
        debounceJob = coroutineScope.launch {
            delay(waitMs)
            destinationFunction(param)
        }
    }
}
```

All these operators can be used as follows:

```
val onEmailChange: (String) -> Unit = throttleLatest(
            300L, 
            viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope, 
            viewModel::onEmailChanged
        )
emailView.onTextChanged(onEmailChange)
```

Comment: it would be nice with some output.

Comment: Note that `onTextChanged()` is not in the Android SDK, though [this post](https://theengineerscafe.com/useful-kotlin-extension-functions-android/) contains an implementation that is compatible.

Comment: I'm calling like this: `protected fun throttleClick(clickAction: (Unit) -> Unit) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            throttleFirst(scope = this, action = clickAction)
        }
    }` but nothing happens, it just returns, the **throttleFirst** returning `fun`  doesn't fire. Why?

Comment: @GuilhE These three functions are not suspending, so you don't have to call them inside a coroutine scope. As for throttling clicks, I usually handle it on the fragment/activity side, something like 
`val invokeThrottledAction = throttleFirst(lifecycleScope, viewModel::doSomething); button.setOnClickListener { invokeThrottledAction()  }`
Basically you have to first create a function object and then call it whenever you need.

Comment: Ok @Terenfear I got it now, thanks for your explanation. Regarding the coroutine scope, since we have a delay we need a coroutine scope, I've just abstracted that from the ViewModel caller (I'm using Data Binding) the clicks aren't created in the View) and that code is in a "BaseViewModel". Or you are saying that instead of `launch` to get a scope I could just call `val ViewModel.viewModelScope: CoroutineScope` since I'm already inside a ViewModel (if so, you are correct)? Btw, really helpful functions, thanks!

Comment: Why 2nd, 3rd or 4th call etc. does not see Job as null?

Comment: @I.Step let's take `fun <T> debounce(...)` for example, it's the same with other functions. We call it once and it creates a function object of type `(T) -> Unit`, which is kinda similar to to an object of anonymous Java class with one method. A Job reference is contained inside that object (kinda like inside a private field of an anonymous Java class). Each time something happens we use (call) the same function object. So, it doesn't matter how many times we call, it is the same object that has the same Job reference.
I might be slightly wrong with the terms, but that's how I understand it.

Comment: I'm having trouble getting viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope inside an Adapter (or even in my fragment!) Where does this come from?

I could find viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle in the fragment, but there is no LifecycleScope.

Comment: @AlanNelson `viewLifecyleOwner.lifecycleScope` comes from the `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.2.0`. Here's more info: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#lifecyclescope

Comment: This `throttleLatest`, in contrast to RxJava's, does not emit the first value immediately. This is more similar to `throttleLast`, see [the difference](https://proandroiddev.com/throttling-in-rxjava-2-d640ea5f7bf1). BTW, `debounce` and `sample` (=`throttleLast`) are already implemented in Kotlin Flows, but `throttleLatest` is [tricky to implement](https://proandroiddev.com/from-rxjava-to-kotlin-flow-throttling-ed1778847619).

Comment: Just found a [simple implementation](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1107#issuecomment-1083076517) of `throttleLatest`. And if your Flow is already conflated (e.g. `StateFlow`), you can just `delay` at the end of the collector.

Comment: In this cases I realize how bad I am at real thinking in functions. Thank you, very insightful.

Comment: The Emperor's New Clothes. This solution is unreadable and overcomplicated. + throttleLatest not taking the last value. KISS.

Answer (score 25):

A more simple and generic solution is to use a function that returns a function that does the debounce logic, and store that in a val.

```
fun <T> debounce(delayMs: Long = 500L,
                   coroutineContext: CoroutineContext,
                   f: (T) -> Unit): (T) -> Unit {
    var debounceJob: Job? = null
    return { param: T ->
        if (debounceJob?.isCompleted != false) {
            debounceJob = CoroutineScope(coroutineContext).launch {
                delay(delayMs)
                f(param)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now it can be used with:

```
val handleClickEventsDebounced = debounce<Unit>(500, coroutineContext) {
    doStuff()
}

fun initViews() {
   myButton.setOnClickListener { handleClickEventsDebounced(Unit) }
}
```

Comment: I am following your logic for my debounce code. However in my case, doStuff() accepts params. Is there a way I can pass params while calling "handleClickEventsDebounced" which then gets passed down to doStuff()?

Comment: Sure, this snippet supports it.  In the example above `handleClickEventsDebounced(Unit)` `Unit` is the param.  It can be any type that you would like since we using generics.  For a String for example do this:
val handleClickEventsDebounced = debounce<String> = debounce<String>(500, coroutineContext) { doStuff(it) }
Where 'it' is the string passed.  Or name it with { myString -> doStuff(myString) }

Comment: Hello @Patrick, can you help me with this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59413001/1423773? I bet it's missing a minor detail, but I can't find it.

Comment: This remembers me of JavaScript's Underscore implementation, which I really like for the simplicity. Congrats and thanks!

Comment: This implementation does not debounce but it throttles.

Answer (score 25):

I use a [callbackFlow](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/callback-flow.html) and [debounce](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/debounce.html) from [Kotlin Coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines-overview.html) to achieve debouncing. For example, to achieve debouncing of a button click event, you do the following:

Create an extension method on `Button` to produce a `callbackFlow`:

```
fun Button.onClicked() = callbackFlow<Unit> {
    setOnClickListener { offer(Unit) }
    awaitClose { setOnClickListener(null) }
}
```

Subscribe to the events within your life-cycle aware activity or fragment. The following snippet debounces click events every 250ms:

```
buttonFoo
    .onClicked()
    .debounce(250)
    .onEach { doSomethingRadical() }
    .launchIn(lifecycleScope)
```

Comment: This solution seems did not work goodly. you must handle the first click without delay request

Comment: @JavidSattar, I'm not sure what you mean? The first click will proceed as normal but following events are ignored for the duration of the timeout. https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/debounce.html

Comment: After testing, I realized that it does not manage the first click correctly

Answer (score 14):

I have created a single extension function from the old answers of stack overflow:

```
fun View.clickWithDebounce(debounceTime: Long = 600L, action: () -> Unit) {
    this.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
        private var lastClickTime: Long = 0

        override fun onClick(v: View) {
            if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - lastClickTime < debounceTime) return
            else action()

            lastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
        }
    })
}
```

View onClick using below code:

```
buttonShare.clickWithDebounce { 
   // Do anything you want
}
```

Comment: Yes! I don't know why so many answers here are complicating this with coroutines.

Comment: This is a throttling method, not a debouncing method.  Throttling keeps the first input. Debouncing only keeps the last input.  This answer is useful for buttons, but isn't as useful for toggle switches or anything else with state.

Comment: This is by far the simplest way to create a throttle extension in Kotlin without using coroutines, rx, etc. I needed to modify the function, because I believe every click should count, so even though a click was throttled it still should set "lastClickTime". So before you return from the function without running "action()" set "lastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()".

Answer (score 9):

Thanks to https://medium.com/@pro100svitlo/edittext-debounce-with-kotlin-coroutines-fd134d54f4e9 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/50007453/2914140 I wrote this code:

```
private var textChangedJob: Job? = null
private lateinit var textListener: TextWatcher

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

    textListener = object : TextWatcher {
        private var searchFor = "" // Or view.editText.text.toString()

        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {}

        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
            val searchText = s.toString().trim()
            if (searchText != searchFor) {
                searchFor = searchText

                textChangedJob?.cancel()
                textChangedJob = launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    delay(500L)
                    if (searchText == searchFor) {
                        loadList(searchText)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    editText.setText("")
    loadList("")
}


override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    editText.addTextChangedListener(textListener)
}

override fun onPause() {
    editText.removeTextChangedListener(textListener)
    super.onPause()
}


override fun onDestroy() {
    textChangedJob?.cancel()
    super.onDestroy()
}
```

I didn't include `coroutineContext` here, so it probably won't work, if not set. For information see [Migrate to Kotlin coroutines in Android with Kotlin 1.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52977239/migrate-to-kotlin-coroutines-in-android-with-kotlin-1-3/53117790).

Comment: Sorry, I understood, that if we run several queries, they would return asynchronously. So, it is not guaranteed, that the last request will return last data and you will update a view with correct data.

Comment: Also, as I understood, `textChangedJob?.cancel()` won't cancel a request in Retrofit. So, be ready that you will get all responses from all requests in random sequence.

Comment: Possibly a new version of Retrofit (2.6.0) will help.

Answer (score 5):

Using tags seems to be a more reliable way especially when working with `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` views.

e.g.

```
fun View.debounceClick(debounceTime: Long = 1000L, action: () -> Unit) {
    setOnClickListener {
        when {
            tag != null && (tag as Long) > System.currentTimeMillis() -> return@setOnClickListener
            else -> {
                tag = System.currentTimeMillis() + debounceTime
                action()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
debounceClick {
    // code block...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

@masterwork,

Great answer. This is my implementation for a dynamic searchbar with an EditText. This provides great performance improvements so the search query is not performed immediately on user text input.

```
    fun AppCompatEditText.textInputAsFlow() = callbackFlow {
        val watcher: TextWatcher = doOnTextChanged { textInput: CharSequence?, _, _, _ ->
            offer(textInput)
        }
        awaitClose { this@textInputAsFlow.removeTextChangedListener(watcher) }
    }
```

```
        searchEditText
                .textInputAsFlow()
                .map {
                    val searchBarIsEmpty: Boolean = it.isNullOrBlank()
                    searchIcon.isVisible = searchBarIsEmpty
                    clearTextIcon.isVisible = !searchBarIsEmpty
                    viewModel.isLoading.value = true
                    return@map it
                }
                .debounce(750) // delay to prevent searching immediately on every character input
                .onEach {
                    viewModel.filterPodcastsAndEpisodes(it.toString())
                    viewModel.latestSearch.value = it.toString()
                    viewModel.activeSearch.value = !it.isNullOrBlank()
                    viewModel.isLoading.value = false
                }
                .launchIn(lifecycleScope)
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

@masterwork's answer worked perfectly fine. Here it is for ImageButton with compiler warnings removed:

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi // This is still experimental API
fun ImageButton.onClicked() = callbackFlow<Unit> {
    setOnClickListener { offer(Unit) }
    awaitClose { setOnClickListener(null) }
}

// Listener for button
val someButton = someView.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.some_button)
someButton
    .onClicked()
    .debounce(500) // 500ms debounce time
    .onEach {
        clickAction()
    }
    .launchIn(lifecycleScope)
```

Comment: This solution seems did not work goodly.
you must handle the first click without delay request

Answer (score 1):

```
object ActionDelayer {

var isActionTriggered = false

fun delay(milliseconds: Long = 10000, scope: CoroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO), action: () -> Unit) {
    if (!isActionTriggered) {
        scope.launch {
            action()
            isActionTriggered = true

            Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().schedule({
                isActionTriggered = false
            }, milliseconds, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        }
    }
}
}
```

Usage:

ActionDelayer.delay { println("Repeating...") }

Answer (score 1):

Tested. This works for me.

##### Create a class

```
class DebounceJob {
    private var job: Job? = null

    fun debounce(
        delayMs: Long = 500L,
        scope: CoroutineScope,
        func: () -> Unit,
    ): () -> Unit {
        job?.cancel()
        return {
            job = scope.launch {
                delay(delayMs)
                func()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

##### How to use

```
let debouceA = DebounceJob()

debouceA.debounce(2000, scope) {
    anotherFunc()
}.invoke(Unit)
```

Comment: Advice: This should be a `class` instead if you're planning to use it from multiple places. Doing so, `job` will be localised to an instance, and not overall app/program.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a simple class to encapsulate the global variable and provide a convenience way to achieve debounce effect.

```
class Debouncer(
    private val scope: CoroutineScope,
    private val delay: Long,
    factory: Debouncer.() -> DebounceAction,
) {
    private var job: Job? = null
    private var onAction: DebounceAction = factory()

    fun startDebounce() {
        job?.cancel()
        job = scope.launch {
            delay(delay)
            onAction.run()
        }
    }
}

fun interface DebounceAction {
    fun run()
}
```

Here i'm separating the startDebounce() to better control when the debounce should happen. The usage:

```
Debouncer(lifecycleScope, 3000) {
    var count = 0
    binding.btn.setOnClickListener {
        count++
        startDebounce()
    }

    // action on debounce
    DebounceAction {
        count = 0
    }
}
```

With the extension, the usage is more natural:

```
fun CoroutineScope.debounce(
    delay: Long,
    factory: Debouncer.() -> DebounceAction,
): Debouncer {
    return Debouncer(this, delay, factory)
}

lifecycleScope.debounce(3000) {
    var count = 0
    binding.btn.setOnClickListener {
        count++
        startDebounce()
    }

    // action on debounce
    DebounceAction {
        count = 0
    }
}
```

You can also add more functionality, such debounce listener like this:

```
private val onDebounceListeners: MutableList<DebounceListener> = mutableListOf()
fun startDebounce() {
    onDebounceListeners.onEach { it.onDebounce() }
    ...
    ...
}
fun addOnDebounceListener(block: () -> Unit): Debouncer {
    onDebounceListeners.add(block)
    return this
}
fun removeOnDebounceListener(listener: DebounceListener): Debouncer {
    onDebounceListeners.remove(listener)
    return this
}
fun debounceImmediate() = onAction
```

And then..

```
lifecycleScope.debounce(3000) {
    var count = 0
    binding.btn.setOnClickListener {
        count++
        startDebounce()
        if (count == 10) {
            // do something
            ..
            ..
            // when you wanna trigger it manually
            debounceImmediate()
        }
    }

    // action on debounce
    DebounceAction {
        count = 0
    }
}.addOnDebounceListener {
    // do when debounce happen
}.addOnDebounceListener { 
    // do other thing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone needs more easy kotlin extension here it is

```
fun EditText.debounce(delay: Long, action: (CharSequence?) -> Unit) {

 doAfterTextChanged { text ->
    val counter = getTag(id) as? Int ?: 0
    handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(counter)
    handler.postDelayed(delay, ++counter) { action(text) }
    setTag(id, counter)
   }
 }
```

Uses

```
val editText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText)

editText.debounce(500) {
   if (it.isNotEmpty()) {
      // Submit the form
     }
  }
```