# Migrate to Kotlin coroutines in Android with Kotlin 1.3

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

What should I change in my `build.gradle` file or import in classes to use stable coroutine functions in my Android project with Kotlin 1.3 ?

Fragment about coroutines in my `build.gradle`

`implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-coroutines-core:$coroutines_version"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-coroutines-android:$coroutines_version"`

Of course I use Android Studio 3.3 Preview

Comment: Kotlin 1.3 is not release yet. You have to use EAP, if you want Kotlin 1.3

Comment: I' am using it, but I think I do not migrate to Kotlin 1.3 correctly. I have an error on my implementation of coroutine libraries in gradle "`library should be updated to be compatible with kotlin 1.3`"

Comment: I can't find any info what version is properly.

Comment: Add `http://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap`. Current Kotlin is `1.3.0-rc-190`. Make sure you update Kotlin plugin as well. Also, it is `org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core` and `org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android`

Comment: Thanks Joshua for response! My teammate helped me to find the solution. I had to increase the coroutines version to 1.0.0-RC1

Comment: @Joshua Your info is already outdated, the RC version is on Maven Central.

Answer (score 28):

In `build.gradle` change a library to

`implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.1.1'`.

Remove, if was added:

```
kotlin {
    experimental {
        coroutines "enable"
    }
}
```

In code change `launch` to `GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO)` or `GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main)`.

**UPDATE**

Please, use local coroutine context instead of global scope (see, for instance, http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/coroutine-context-and-dispatchers.html).

**For Activity**

See https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/ui/coroutines-guide-ui.md.

Implement `CoroutineScope`:

```
class YourActivity : AppCompatActivity(), CoroutineScope {
```

Add a local variable `job` and initialize it:

```
private lateinit var job: Job

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    job = Job()
}
```

Create a coroutine context and cancel it on Activity destroy:

```
override fun onDestroy() {
    job.cancel()
    super.onDestroy()
}

override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
    get() = Dispatchers.Main + job
```

**For Fragment** (the same as in `Activity`)

Implement CoroutineScope:

```
class YourFragment : Fragment(), CoroutineScope {
```

Create a local variable `job` and initialize it in `onCreate()`. (I tried to write `private val job: Job = Job()`, but bumped into problem that in `ViewPager` you will create `Fragment`s and their jobs. As we will cancel the `job` in `onDestroy()` during swiping in `ViewPager`, we should recreate the job).

```
private lateinit var job: Job

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    ...
    job = Job()
}
```

Create a coroutine context and cancel it on Fragment destroy:

```
override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
    get() = Dispatchers.Main + job // You can use different variants here. 

override fun onDestroy() {
    job.cancel()
    super.onDestroy()
}
```

**A launch example**

Use `launch` as usual:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    launch {
        // Wait for result of I/O operation without blocking the main thread.
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            interactor.getCountry().let {
                countryName = it.name
            }
        }

        // Update views in the UI thread.
        country.updateCaption(countryName)
    }
}
```

In my case a problem occured when I used API requests with usual callbacks. A `launch` interior inside a callback hasn't been called. So I rewrote that code with interactors.

Answer (score 7):

My teammate helped me to find the solution. I had to increase the coroutines version to 1.0.0-RC1. For everyone who may don't know about the changes in using Android coroutines:

- I had to change the UI context of coroutine to Dispatchers.Main
- I used old experimental coroutines version (0.23 maybe) so for everyone who don't know - now launch is deprecated and you should use structured concurrency (for example `coroutineScope`) instead.
- Now async function cannot be run outside the scope.

I hope I will help someone. Don't waste a time. Happy programming!

Answer (score 0):

The *implementation version* must be >= the *testing version*

### build.gradle (:mobile)

```
dependencies {
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$coroutines")

    // Testing
    testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:$coroutines"
    androidTestImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:$coroutines"
}
```

### build.gradle (Project)

```
buildscript {
    ...
    ext.coroutines = '1.3.6'
}
```

---

### FAILURE FIXED

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugAndroidTestRuntimeClasspath'.
    > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.5.
    Required by:
        project :app
     > Cannot find a version of 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core' that satisfies the version constraints:
          Dependency path 'Open Weather:app:unspecified' --> 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.5'
```

GL

Answer (score 0):

Simply add "mavenCentral()" to build.gradle bellow build script: I fixed using this.

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.72'

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral() //Add this Line only <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for `mavenCentral()` in `allprojects repositories`! I am replacing `jcenter()` with `maven()`, because `jCenter` will close in May.