# Wait until Kotlin coroutine finishes in onCreateView()

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, kotlin-coroutines

I have an initialization block in `onCreateView`, where some variables are assigned from SharedPreferences, DB or Network (currently from SharedPreferences).

I want to update views with these values in `onViewCreated`. But they update with empty values before a coroutine in `onCreateView` finishes. How to wait until the coroutine finishes in main thread?

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    ...
    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
        val job = GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val task = async(Dispatchers.IO) {
                settingsInteractor.getStationSearchCountry().let {
                    countryName = it.name
                }
                settingsInteractor.getStationSearchRegion().let {
                    regionName = it.name
                }
            }
            task.await()
        }
        job.join()
    }
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    country.updateCaption(countryName)
    region.updateCaption(regionName)
}
```

UPDATE (20-05-2019)

Currently I don't use `onViewCreated`. I write code in `onCreate` and `onCreateView`. In `onCreateView` I access views this way: `view.country.text = "abc"` and so on.

Answer (score 6):

It's better to use `async` instead of `launch` https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/async.html.

Create `lateinit val dataLoad: Deferred<Pair<String, String>`. init it as `dataLoad = GlobalScope.async(Dispatchers.Defailt) {}` in `onCreateView` or earlier.
`launch` new coroutine in UI scope in `onViewCreated`. Wait for result in that coroutine `val data = dataLoad.await()` and then apply data to ui

Comment: Yes, that's a good variant. Probably I will follow if make an initialization in UI thread.

Answer (score 5):

In your case you don't need to use `GlobalScope` as a coroutine context (you can but it is not recommended as per docs). You need a local scope:

```
private var job: Job = Job()
override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
    get() = Dispatchers.Main + job

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    job.cancel()
}
```

Also your fragment should implement `CoroutineScope` and to use `Dispatchers.Main` in Android add dependency to app's build.gradle:

```
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.0.1'
```

The code to wait until the coroutine finishes:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    launch {
        val operation = async(Dispatchers.IO) {
            settingsInteractor.getStationSearchCountry().let {
                countryName = it.name
            }
            settingsInteractor.getStationSearchRegion().let {
                regionName = it.name
            }
        }
        operation.await() // wait for result of I/O operation without blocking the main thread

        // update views
        country.updateCaption(countryName)
        region.updateCaption(regionName)
    }
}
```

EDIT:

In `Activity` or `Fragment` you can use `lifecycleScope` instead of implementing `CoroutineScope`:

```
lifecycleScope.launch { ... }
```

To use `lifecycleScope` add next line to dependencies of the app's **build.gradle** file:

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$LIFECYCLE_VERSION"
```

At the time of writing final LIFECYCLE_VERSION = "2.3.0-alpha05"

Comment: Thanks! I tested this code. Maybe it's similar to @ArtemBotnev answer, but you hinted me how to make a coroutine context. Before I didn't know how to create it.

Comment: By now it has been well established that you should _not_ use `async-await` for non-concurrent code. You should write `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)`. This is especially relevant due to a very different and non-intuitive way that `async` treats exceptions that aren't handled within its body.

Comment: Should we cancel a job on fragment recreate? For instance, if some request has uploaded a bitmap and we rotate a screen, should we can cancel it?

Comment: You can cancel it. When fragment is recreated it should launch coroutine again. You can use `setRetainInstance(true)` method to prevent recreation of the fragment.

Comment: @Sergey, I had a problem with recreating fragments' jobs in `ViewPager` and changed this code, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/53117790/2914140. В общем, корутины не запускались в новых фрагментах, пока не начал создавать job по-новой.

Answer (score -1):

Use [runBlocking](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/run-blocking.html). In this case you can *block UI thread* until coroutine completion. Of course, you are to be sure it will be fast enough (less than 3 sec) to not raise ANR.

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    ...
    val (countryName, regionName) = runBlocking {
        // Switch to background thread and continue blocking UI thread.
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val countryName = settingsInteractor.getStationSearchCountry().let {
                it.name
            }
            val regionName = settingsInteractor.getStationSearchRegion().let {
                it.name
            }
            countryName to regionName
        }
    }

    // Assign data after runBlocking has finished.
    view.country_name.text = countryName
    view.region_name.text = regionName

    return view
}
```

I didn't test it, because use similar code in `onBackPressed`. When I quit a fragment (or an activity) I should write some data in DB. If running too late, `onDestroy` will be called and coroutines will be finished. In this case data won't be written to DB. So, I have to stop UI thread, write to DB in background thread, then return to UI. `runBlocking` works well.