# Coroutine doens't start?

Tags: android, higher-order-functions, kotlin-coroutines, coroutinescope, androidx-lifecycle

Based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50858684/kotlin-android-debounce/55802898#55802898) `throttleFirst` function:

```
fun <T> throttleFirst(
    skipMs: Long = 700L,
    scope: CoroutineScope = viewModelScope,
    action: (T) -> Unit
): (T) -> Unit {
    var throttleJob: Job? = null
    return { param: T ->
        if (throttleJob?.isCompleted != false) {
            throttleJob = coroutineScope.launch {
                destinationFunction(param)
                delay(skipMs)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using it like this:

**View**

```
<Button
    android:onClick="@{viewModel.myClickListener}"
.../>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
fun myClickListener() = View.OnClickListener { _ ->
    throttleClick(clickAction = {
        //do things
    })
}
```

**BaseViewModel**:

```
protected fun throttleClick(millis: Long = 700L, clickAction: (Unit) -> Unit): (Unit) -> Unit  {
    throttleFirst(millis, scope = viewModelScope, action = clickAction)
}
```

But nothing happens, the **clickAction** is not reached. While debugging, step-by-step ends when it hits `return { param: T ->` and that returning function (`throttleJob?.isCompleted`... code) is never called.
What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT** with the help from [**Patrick**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/751581/patrick) the final solution is:

**ViewModel**

```
private val myThrottleClick = throttleClick(clickAction = {
    //do things
})

fun myClickListener() = View.OnClickListener { myThrottleClick(Unit) }
```

**BaseViewModel**

```
protected fun throttleClick(millis: Long = 700L, clickAction: (Unit) -> Unit): (Unit) -> Unit {
    return throttleFirst(millis, action = clickAction)
}
```

Comment: what are you clicking?

Comment: @coroutineDispatcher Post updated. Used inside a `Button` from xml. I'm using `Data Binding`

Comment: i think the return type of `throttleFirst(...)` is a function reference (lambda). you should some where in your code invoke it. `throttleFirst(..).invoke()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `throttleFirst` function makes a click listener, so you must store it in a val outside of your click listeners scope.  i.e.

```
val clickListener = throttleFirst { doStuff() }

fun myClickListener() = View.OnClickListener { _ -> clickListener() }
```

You may be able to do away with the `myClickListener` function entirely and just reference `clickListener` in xml.

Comment: Ok got it, only missing one thing, `clickListener()` asks me for parameter. I would like to use Unit but I can't instantiate "void", so how do you suggest I solve this minor detail?

Comment: You can remove the parame from the clickAction.  clickAction: () -> Unit.
Alternatively you can pass Unit as a param.

Comment: I'll use the second approach because I don't want to change the `throttleFirst` function, instead create a "proxy/helper" `throttleClick` to use it. That said, the second approach is the one to follow :) 
I was being dumb because I was calling clickListener(Unit()) instead of clickListener(Unit)... ^^ thanks a lot Patrick!