# how make delay in compose function

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I make a simple field with validation:

```
@Composable
private fun MyField(value:String) {
    OutlinedTextField(
        value = value,
        onValueChange = {
        { value = it },
        modifier = Modifier,
        label = {
            Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.field))
        },
        isError = value.length < 5
    )
    if (value.length < 5) {
        Text(
            text = stringResource(R.string.field_nor_valid),
            color = Color.Black
        )
    }
}
```

I want to change field color during inputting if it is <5. But I want change it through 3 second.That is, I want to validate not immediately, while the user types, but after some time. How can I do that?

Comment: I think you have also a typo value.lenth = value.length

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To delay the validation by 3 seconds after the user types in a Jetpack Compose TextField, you can utilize the **LaunchedEffect** composable in tandem with **kotlinx.coroutines.delay**.

```
@Composable
private fun MyField(value: MutableState<String>) {
    var isError by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    OutlinedTextField(
        value = value.value,
        onValueChange = {
            value.value = it
            LaunchedEffect(it) {
                delay(3000)  // the delay of 3 seconds
                isError = it.length < 5
            }
        },
        modifier = Modifier,
        label = {
            Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.field))
        },
        isError = isError
    )
    if (isError) {
        Text(
            text = stringResource(R.string.field_not_valid),
            color = Color.Black
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I tryied to do this, but I get an error, that `LaunchedEffect` `@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function`

Comment: I just moved  `LaunchedEffect(it) {
                delay(3000)  // the delay of 3 seconds
                isError = it.length < 5
            }` after `OutlinedTextField` . Thanks for your answer. Can I observe that the user started input again and hide error?

Comment: You should never block MainThread like this:```LaunchedEffect(it) {
                delay(3000)  // the delay of 3 seconds
                isError = it.length < 5
            }``` It's a bad practice

Comment: I would recommend you to use `debounce()`. Its very easy to implement using kotlin flows - https://stackoverflow.com/a/57252799/19212377

Comment: @Megh, that doesn't block the main thread. `delay()` is a suspend function. It doesn't block.

Comment: You should not be using a mutable parameter for a Composable function, though! It can work, but it is error-prone and doesn't follow encapsulation principles of programming. State should be hoisted.